# Cannot convert lambda expression with ServiceStack SELECT

Tags: c#, linq, sqlite, lambda, servicestack

I try to made a simple SELECT with a where condition, I get the error message "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'ServiceStack.Ormlite,SqlExpressions' because it is not a delegate type".

There is my code:

> ```
>     // Return on object of the last raw of the PatientGatewaySoftware stored
>     public PatientGatewaySoftwareUpdate GetLastRow(PatientGatewaySoftwareUpdate p)
>     {
>         int version = p.SoftwareVersion;
>         return _dbConnection.Select<PatientGatewaySoftwareUpdate>(q => q.Where(x => x.SoftwareVersion = version));
>     }
> ```

I use those assemblies:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Web;
using ServiceStack.DataAnnotations;
using ServiceStack;
using ServiceStack.OrmLite;
```

I don't think have made a mistake on my request, maybe it's a particular assembly for ServiceStack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have missed an `=` mark in the `Where` clause:

```
return _dbConnection.Select<PatientGatewaySoftwareUpdate>(q => 
    q.Where(x => x.SoftwareVersion == version));
```